# How to fix CORS error on localhost when connecting to a local Appwrite from a local React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, appwrite

I'm using the web SDK for Appwrite in a React app:

```
const client = new Client()
    .setEndpoint(import.meta.env.URL)
    .setProject(import.meta.env.PROJECT_ID)

  const account = new Account(client);

  const promise = account.create(ID.unique(),
    "some@email.com",
    "somepassword");

  promise.then(
    function (response: any) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    function (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
```

In the Appwrite GUI I have configured a Web App platform with localhost domain.
My React app works on localhost.

- The endpoint name and project name match data from Appwrite
  dashboard.
- App is started on http, the API is also set up on http.
- I've indicated localhost as a place where the API calls will come
  from
- The app is under http://localhost:5173/ and API on
  http://localhost:8455.

In the console I get an error:

```
POST http://localhost:8455/account net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8455/account' from origin 'http://localhost:5173'
has been blocked by CORS policy:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How to fix that error?

Comment: Did you set backend CORS?

Comment: The port numbers have to match also, or else the server has to set CORS headers for the client host/port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the URL is correct. Ensure the endpoint includes the `/v1` like `http://localhost:8455/v1`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install the cors package in your backend folder as:

```
npm install cors
```

and then you have to set the variables as:

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

then you maynot face this problem. This may help you

Comment: He is talking about AppWrite. It'a serverless service.